# Apps not loaded yet when using actstream django

Tags: python, django

So i'm trying to create an application for user interaction with stream_django. So far everything was going well until I got error:
 'User model not registered. Please register model with actstream.registry'.

So after searching for some time, I modified my apps.py to be like this:
 The project is called reviews

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals


import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "reviews.settings")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "reviews.settings"
django.setup()

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        from actstream import registry
        registry.register(User,self.get_model('Post'),self.get_model('UserProfile'))
```

But now I'm getting error:
 'AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet")'
I'm not sure what to do anymore, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem but I found that the solution was to add the **default_app_config** setting in the **__init__.py** of your main project (same location as your **settings.py**).

For your case, that **__init__.py** file should look like this:

```
# reviews/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Also adding: apps.get _user_model('auth', 'User'), works as per the django docs on registering models. First apps must be imported though. If you could help me with another related problem?  How do you send an action in views or models with request.user?  How exactly do I write it? Thanks